# Is an async javascript evaluated entirely before relinquishing event loop control?

Tags: javascript

I load the Google Maps JS asynchronously:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?....';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

One of my scripts depends on the `google.maps` object it provides, so I check if `google.maps` is defined, and if not, I try again in `200ms`:

```
initializeGoogleMaps: function() {
  if (typeof google === 'undefined') {
    window.setTimeout(this.initializeGoogleMaps.bind(this), 200);
  } else {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(...)
  }
}
```

However when I look at the Google Maps [script](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&components=country:us) that's getting loaded, it begins like this:

```
window.google = window.google || {};
google.maps = google.maps || {};
(function() {
  // then a lot more
```

**Here's my question:** Do I have a race condition here? Is it possible for a `setTimeout` to fire *while* an async script is being evaluated? Visually:

```
// This is the googleapis.com 3rd party script. It has been downloaded
// by the browser, and is now in the process of being evaluated.

window.google = window.google || {}; // google is now defined
google.maps = google.maps || {};     // google.maps is now defined

// ==== Can my setTimeout fire here? =====
// My `if (typeof google === 'undefined')` would be
// FALSE here, even though this script has not finished loading!
// Or, due to the single thread, will the browser finish evaluating
// this script before allowing queued up setTimeouts to fire?
// =======================================

(function() {
  // then a lot more
```

I know JS is in some sense single threaded, but I wasn't sure how that played with async scripts. When an async script starts to get evaluated, does it finish loading the whole file before control is relinquished back to the event loop for other async scripts and setTimeout callbacks?

Comment: The JS runtime with run your whole script and won't wait for anything. You should use promises, callbacks, or some async library to fetch the Google Maps data. I recommend you to use RxJS

Comment: Can you use promises, etc, to load the Google Maps *script* (not data)? My concern is that the browser could be midway through evaluating the Google Maps script when my setTimeout callback fires.

Comment: Using async patterns you can get rid of those setTimeout functions and render the resulting data once is available

Comment: Thanks, that very well could work if I were building this from scratch, but I'm constrained by existing code. My solution above works with minimal invasiveness, as long as the `setTimeout` can't fire while the runtime is evaluating the external script. So I would still love to know the answer to my specific question.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have a race condition here?

Nope. JavaScript is "single-threaded", which means that every script and every callback is completely evaluated ("run to completion") before the next on (in the event loop) will start.

> Is it possible for a setTimeout to fire while an async script is being evaluated?

Technically, the timeout can expire while the script is still being evaluated (quite likely when the script takes a long time to execute), but when it expires that doesn't mean the callback is immediately executed, it is just scheduled to be run as soon as possible (after the current event loop turn finishes).

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you're asking about will likely be inconsistent among different browsers and should not be relied on. If the script executions happen on different threads with a shared state, what you're afraid of is possible. This however is not likely given the asynchronous design choices in Javascript. If the scripts are executed on the event loop, they are executed sequentially in full.

I would nevertheless go with using asynchronous patterns like [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) now [native to modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) or simply use the Google Maps `<script>` element's [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts) event like so:

```
var maps_script = document.createElement('script');
maps_script.type = 'text/javascript';
maps_script.async = true;
maps_script.onload = initializeGoogleMaps;
maps_script.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?...';
```

`setTimeout` is not a very effective way to manage causally-related events, especially when event handlers, callbacks and promises are available expressly for that purpose.